# How can I get my XSLT transformation to work with large XML?

Tags: xslt, transformation, httpmodule

I have written code to filter out new XML elements that have been introduced as part of web service enhancements. The transformation seems to work with small XML but as soon as I increase the size its stops working. Using SoapUI, it simply returns a blank response.

Can anyone help? Do i need to alter the code below to handle large XML?

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        //clean-up code here.
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler       (context_PreRequestHandlerExecute);
    }

    void context_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
        State state = (State)app.Context.Items["VersionManagerState"];
        if (state.ProcessRequest)
        {
            Stream xslres = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(string.Concat("TestService.VersionManager.",state.Version, ".xslt"));
            if (xslres != null)
            {
                state.Xsl = new XslCompiledTransform();
                state.Xsl.Load(XmlReader.Create(xslres));
                app.Context.Response.Filter = new OutputFilterStream(state, app.Context.Response.Filter);
            }
        }

    }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
        State state = new State();
        app.Context.Items["VersionManagerState"] = state;

        if (app.Context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith(".asmx") && app.Request.RequestType == "POST")
        {
            state.ProcessRequest = true;
            app.Context.Request.Filter = new InputFilterStream(state, app.Context.Request.Filter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Language? Anyway feed it from a SAX parser, not a DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Language is C#. Do you have an example of using a SAX parser?